# Leaflet more than 10 clickable icons on a map

Tags: hyperlink, leaflet, markers

my problem now is complicated to explain. I want to put on a map a lot of markers. If you click on a link, you see the marker popup that opens.
I noticed that if the marker number is larger than 9, there is no id.
How to fix it?

```
function markerFunction(id){
                for (var i in markers){
                    var markerID = markers[i].options.title;
                    alert(id);


                    if (markerID == id){
                        markers[i].openPopup();
                    };

                }
            }

            $("a").click(function(){
                markerFunction($(this)[0].id);

            });
```

Comment: Bienvenu sur SO ! There should normally be no technical difficulty in the use case you describe. We would probably need more details on your links. It looks like you use the link document ID to match it with the title of your markers? There would be multiple alternate ways to achieve the behaviour of opening a marker's popup from a link outside the map.

Comment: I followed this link : http://jsfiddle.net/abenrob/ZkC5M/.But if you have another way to get any easier, I will that you me explain.
I do not understand exactly why it's not working. But what I know is that id is null above 10.

Comment: In a function I search and I then displays the result.

Comment: It's good I found. I rewrote the function twice. so the code is good.

Comment: This example I just forked from your fiddle seems fine with a `marker_10`. http://jsfiddle.net/ZkC5M/216/ Can you provide an example of the broken behavior you are talking about?

Comment: @snkashis I confirm that works even if I think that this way of linking marker to links is bad.